# Animation: Getting Different Image Look in Each Frame

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When rendering an animation with multiple frames of the same image, I am getting different results in each frame! Please see my rendered images in the following link for clarification: [Animation Issue](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12ILPSgiicr27-K9OhTb9jRrp40hLjD7s?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you upload some significant images here instead of providing a link to Google drive? Thanks

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this looks like a typical result of biased global illumation (secondary bounces). Bump up your samples (which increases your render times), rework your lighting or bake the lighting into textures.